# Angular 2 routing with fragments, async data

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular2-routing, observable, timing

I am building a site that includes one home page of many sections and two additional pages. Each section is its own component. The bottom section, contact, should be accessible via an anchor link. I have successfully been able to anchor to the contact section while on the home page. When routing to "contact" from a different page, however, I am encountering a timing issue. When I increase the SetTimeOut parameters to 2s instead of 1s, the function works properly. However, this is a hacky solution.

I know that routing with fragments is still buggy in Angular. Could anyone tell me the best way to approach this? I believe that the data loading is slowing the ability to find the anchor when I'm routing to the homepage#contact from the project or press page.

I have tried ng2-page-scroll, as well as tracked this thread: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6595 and tried most of the proposed solutions. Nothing is allowing me to navigate to the contact section on the home page from a different page WITHOUT at least a 2s SetTimeOut.

This is in my home component, which contains the contact component.

```
  ngAfterViewInit(){
  this._route.fragment
    .subscribe(
      (fragment: string) => {
        console.log('is there a fragment?');
        console.log(fragment);
        const element = document.querySelector("#" + fragment)
        if (element) {element.scrollIntoView(); console.log(element);}
        else { console.log('no element i guess '); }
        // if (fragment){
        //   this.scrollToAnchor(fragment, 1000);
        // }
      }
    );
  }
```

This is my nav markup:

```
<li class="nav-li">
   <a
     [routerLink]="['/']"
     fragment="contact"
     class="nav-a"
     (click)="_globalService.toggleNav()">
     contact
   </a>
</li>
```

This is my HomeComponent, which contains the contact section:

```
<div class="homeWrap" id="container">
  <app-splash-graphic id="splash" name="splash"></app-splash-graphic>
  <app-about id="about" name="about"></app-about>
  <app-projects></app-projects>
  <app-press></app-press>
  <div id="contact" name="contact">
      <app-contact></app-contact>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm really at a loss! Any wisdom greatly appreciated.

Comment: I didn't understand the problem. I guess the contact section is in the main page and when the 'contact link' is been clicked, the site firstly loads the main page and scrolls to contact component. Am I right?

Comment: Have you tried to use ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook of contact component instead of  subscribing to router? Thus, you will be sure the component is ready on the page.

Comment: @omeralper I just edited the code above to clarify. The contact section is one section of the homepage. The desired functionality is that when I click the contact link in nav, whether I'm on home component or not, the site will route to the home component and then scroll down to the contact section. I have tried using ngAfterViewInit as well as ngAfterViewCheck. There is a timing problem with the way the page is loading that prevents the scroll from executing, but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a directive for simular situation:

```js
/**
 * directive that causes the browser to scroll and focus to the anchor from the latest activated route fragment
 * usage:
 * link with fragment: <a tabindex="0" [routerLink]="['/']" fragment="contact">
 * html in / route page:
 * <section appFocusFragment>
 *  <a id="contact">First focused content after load</a>
 */
import { Directive, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appFocusFragment]'
})
export class FocusFragmentDirective implements AfterViewInit  {
  private fragment: string;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    // be sure the navigation goes to the # fragment
    this.route.fragment.subscribe(fragment => { this.fragment = fragment; });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    try {
      const anchor = document.querySelector<HTMLAnchorElement>('#' + this.fragment);
      anchor.focus();
      anchor.scrollIntoView();
    } catch (e) { }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure of your code structure but you can probably use Angular routing resolve guard and write your own resolve which will provide you with fully loaded page before navigating to a needed route. I think that this will resolve your timing problem.

https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data

Comment: This could work. Could also pass the fragment/element id that is required to be scrolled into view as part of the resolve, and scroll to it in onViewChecked

Comment: A resolver will not help. I posted a bug report about it [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/33240).